# When routing to another page I get "There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to navigate from one screen to another with route. When I hit the button for the page to move to the route provided I get the error:

```
I/flutter ( 8790): Another exception was thrown: There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
```

Sharing with you the source code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_counter/flutter_counter.dart';
import 'package:gender_selection/gender_selection.dart';
import 'package:group_chats/addContactUI.dart';
import 'package:group_chats/addPhone.dart';
import 'package:group_chats/letGoUI.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'Model/insertUserModel.dart';

class AddProfileUI extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> listFriends;
  final String phone;
  AddProfileUI(this.listFriends, this.phone);
  @override
  _AddProfileUIState createState() => _AddProfileUIState();
}

class _AddProfileUIState extends State<AddProfileUI> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String name = "";
  String city = "";
  TextEditingController dobController = TextEditingController();
  bool single = false;
  Gender gender;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int defaultValue = 18;
  List<String> selectedContact;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  bool _loading = true;

  Future initPrefs() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  uploadImage(String userId) async {
    try {
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
        "file":
            await MultipartFile.fromFile(_image.path, filename: "$userId.jpg"),
      });
      var response = await Dio().post(
          "https://us-central1-app-backend-fc090.cloudfunctions.net/webApi/api/v1/upload_profile/$userId",
          data: formData);
      if (response.statusCode == 200)
        return response.data;
      else
        return null;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<InsertUserModel> insertData() async {
    try {
      for (int i = 0; i < selectedContact.length; i++) {
        if (selectedContact[i][0] == "0") {
          selectedContact[i] = selectedContact[i].replaceRange(0, 1, "+972");
        }
      }
      var body = jsonEncode({
        "gender": gender.index == 0 ? "male" : "female",
        "city": city,
        "last_login": {},
        "friends": selectedContact ?? [],
        "single": single,
        "name": name,
        "phone_number": widget.phone,
        "age": defaultValue
      });
      final String apiUrl =
          "https://us-central1-app-backend-fc090.cloudfunctions.net/webApi/api/v1/users/${AddPhoneUI.uid}";
      final response = await http.post(apiUrl,
          headers: {"content-type": "application/json"}, body: body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseString = response.body;

        return insertUserModelFromJson(responseString);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  getUserData() async {
    try {
      final String apiUrl =
          "https://us-central1-app-backend-fc090.cloudfunctions.net/webApi/api/v1/users/";
      final response = await http.get(apiUrl);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final responseString = response.body;
        return insertUserModelFromJson(responseString);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _loading = false;
      });
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        content: Text('Error: ${e.toString()}'),
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2500),
      ));
    }
  }

  Future<void> _selectStartingDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(1950),
      lastDate: DateTime(
          DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        dobController.text = selectedDate.year.toString() +
            "-" +
            selectedDate.month.toString() +
            "-" +
            selectedDate.day.toString();
      });
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
  }

  showPopUp(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              shape:
                  OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0)),
              content: Container(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "My Profile",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 27.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30.0,
                    ),
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                      text: "Your friends will be able to\nsee ",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                            text: 'only',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        TextSpan(text: 'your picture and\name.'),
                      ],
                    )),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                      text: "Other fields are used for\n",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                            text: 'research issues',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        TextSpan(text: "only."),
                      ],
                    )),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(
                      text: "Please fill all the fields.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 80.0,
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      shape: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0)),
                      color: Colors.white38,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Ok, got it",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedContact = widget.listFriends;
    initPrefs();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => AddContactUI(),
                            )).then((value) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedContact = value;
                          });
                        });
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.supervisor_account,
                            size: 40.0,
                          ),
                          Text("Add Friends"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    await getImage();
                  },
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 60.0,
                    backgroundImage: _image != null
                        ? Image.file(_image).image
                        : Image.asset("assets/empty.png").image,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: FadeAnimation(
                  1.7,
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color(0xff5E17EB).withOpacity(0.3),
                              blurRadius: 20,
                              offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            )
                          ]),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    bottom:
                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]))),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              onFieldSubmitted: (_) =>
                                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() {
                                  name = val;
                                });
                              },
                              validator: (val) =>
                                  val.isEmpty ? "Enter Name" : null,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: "Name",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                    bottom:
                                        BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200]))),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                setState(() {
                                  city = val;
                                });
                              },
                              validator: (val) {
                                if (val.isEmpty) return "Enter City";
//                                      if (val.length < 6)
//                                        return "Password should be at least 6 characters";
                                return null;
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintText: "City",
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 140.0,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: GenderSelection(
                              selectedGender: gender,
                              maleText: "", //default Male
                              femaleText: "", //default Female
                              linearGradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                Colors.indigo,
                                Colors.black
                              ]), //List: [Colors.indigo, Colors.black]
                              selectedGenderIconBackgroundColor:
                                  Colors.indigo, // default red
                              checkIconAlignment:
                                  Alignment.centerRight, // default bottomRight
                              selectedGenderCheckIcon:
                                  null, // default Icons.check
                              onChanged: (Gender gender) {
                                this.gender = gender;
                                print(this.gender);
                              },
                              equallyAligned: true,
                              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                              isCircular: true, // default : true,
                              isSelectedGenderIconCircular: true,
                              opacityOfGradient: 0.6,
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                              size: 120, //default : 120
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Checkbox(
                                value: single,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    single = !single;
                                  });
                                },
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Are you Single?",
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Age:",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                                ),
                                Counter(
                                  initialValue: defaultValue,
                                  buttonSize: 35.0,
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                                  minValue: 0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  maxValue: 80,
                                  step: 1,
                                  decimalPlaces: 0,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    // get the latest value from here
                                    setState(() {
                                      defaultValue = value;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              FadeAnimation(
                1.9,
                MaterialButton(
                  shape: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0)),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Next",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      InsertUserModel result = await insertData();
                      // var imageResult = await uploadImage(result.id);
                      print(result.data[0].id);
                      if (_image != null) {
                        await uploadImage(result.data[0].id);
                      }
                      setState(() {
                        _loading = false;
                      });
                      if (result != null) {
                        await prefs.setString("userID", result.data[0].id);
                        final snackBar = SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                            result.message,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                        );

                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => LetGoUI(result.data[0].id),
                            ));
                      } else {
                        final snackBar = SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                            "Here is some error, please try again later!",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                        );

                        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I really don't understand what is the problem because I'm not using any Heros and not have double `FloatingActionButton`.

How do I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be problem with showing snackbar while navigating. you should remove that problem by calling following method before navigating.

```
void removeSnackBarCallsBeforeNavigation() {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).removeCurrentSnackBar();
  }
```

Comment: Getting error - ════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during a scheduler callback:
There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag.
In this case, multiple heroes had the following tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("Welcome Riya Ji!")>
Here is the subtree for one of the offending heroes: Hero
    tag: <SnackBar Hero tag - Text("Welcome Riya Ji!")>
    state: ....

Comment: you need to use tag if you are using multiple hero widgets in the same screen. if you are using snackbar as well as floating action button this might be the case.

Comment: I am not using any hero widget and also not using any floating action button in my project. I am 100% sure. Any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: according to error you are giving "SnackBar Hero tag" to multiple hero widgets. kindly check if sub widgets are using the same tag, then use other tag.

Comment: dear, as I requested you earlier that I am not using any Hero tag in entire project. So this is not issue related to Hero tag, we will have to think out of the box to fix this issue.

Comment: It is only happening when I show message by Snackbar and just after that redirecting screen/page to another screen/page.